# python - why cannot use double underscore __ in a global name?

Tags: python, global-variables

Please advise the cause of the symptom and what Python resources to look at to understand further.

With `Python 3.8.8` when including `__` in a variable name, it causes the error.

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 24 2021, 21:46:12) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> __HOGE = 1
>>> class hoge:
...     def __init__(
...             self,
...             name: str,
...             num_nodes: int,
...             momentum = 0.9,
...     ):
...         self.args = set(locals().keys())
...         global __HOGE
...         print(__HOGE)
... 
>>> a = hoge(name="name", num_nodes=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in __init__
NameError: name '_hoge__HOGE' is not defined
```

Which does not happen with single underscore `_`.

```
>>> _HOGE = 1
>>> class hoge:
...     def __init__(
...             self,
...             name: str,
...             num_nodes: int,
...             momentum = 0.9,
...     ):
...         self.args = set(locals().keys())
...         global _HOGE
...         print(_HOGE)
... 
>>> a = hoge(name="name", num_nodes=1)
1
```

[PEP 8 Global Variable Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names) does not mention any restriction.

> Modules that are designed for use via from M import * should use the **all** mechanism to prevent exporting globals, or use the older convention of prefixing such globals with an underscore (which you might want to do to indicate these globals are "module non-public").

[Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) neither.

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
> implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within
> the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly
> declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains
> this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a
> bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was
> required for all global references, you’d be using global all the
> time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in
> function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would
> defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying
> side-effects.

Comment: In a class, dunder names are used to create private attributes, so they're automatically prefixed with the class name.

Comment: Double-underscored names get mangled in a class, it is a feature to use when you want to prevent name-collisions in subclasses. Why not just use a single underscore?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, will do. Did not know __ is converted.

Comment: As an aside, `global __HOGE` doesn't do anything and isn't required here because you never try to assign to the global  `__HOGE`